# jQuery change button attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button like this:

```
<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="Proceed"/>
```

After all processes and get the expected result, I need to apply some changes on this button.

1. Change the value of this button.
2. Add something to direct the current page to another one.

I know I can do the first goal using the code below:

```
$('#btn').attr('value','newValue');
```

But for the second one, I need something like our previous codes in JavaScript as below:

```
onclick="window.location.href='newPage.htm'";
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like, if I understand you correctly:

```
$("#btn").val("newValue").click(function(){
     document.location = "newPage.htm";
});
```

This will set a new value and bind a click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#btn").attr("onclick", "window.location.href='newPage.htm'");
```

Or better yet, add a click handler:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    window.location.assign = 'newPage.htm';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
$("#btn").val("newValue").click(function(){
document.location = "newPage.htm"; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $('#btn').attr('value', 'newValue');
        window.location="newPage.htm";
    });
});
</script>
```